# Are there any test cases to ensure the "web-attacks.rules" snort file works correctly?

Tags: web-application, attacks, snort

I have set up an free evaluation [Confluence Server](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/overview/team-collaboration-software) on my local host and have configured "snort.conf" to point to my localhost as "HOME_NET" environment variable.

I tried to test the ICMP rule by running "ping localhost" and I immediately see output in /var/log/snort/alert file.  So I know the ICMP rule works correctly.

However, I cannot get any of the "web-attacks.rules" to work.  For example, how do I test this rule?

```
alert tcp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HTTP_SERVERS any (msg:"WEB-ATTACKS uname -a command attempt"; flow:to_server,established; content:"uname%20-a"; nocase; classtype:web-application-a
```

ttack; sid:1331; rev:5;)

I would appreciate all / any advise in testing any of the "web-attacks.rules". 
In fact, if someone could point me to a test script that triggers all the "web-attacks.rules" that would be ideal.

Thanks.

Comment: You might find [my answer to a previous question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15238/testing-a-snort-ids-installation/15240#15240) helpful. (Athough I don't think this is necessarily a dupe.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually people use a web application firewall to detect/prevent these attacks.  mod_security is an open source WAF.

Any web application vulnerability scanner should do the trick.  Skipfish and wapiti are both open source web application vulnerability scanners.